# Evaluating variable importance

Tags: data-mining, data-modeling, data-analysis

I'm working for the moment on a project of data analysis, and i just come throught some notions that seemed trivial to me, for instance, the concept of variable importance, i would like to know if there is a formula (or an approach) to evaluate this quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are plenty.

It's called **feature selecrion**.